# Parallelization Fortran 90

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, fortran, fortran90

I recently started to learn how to parallelize programs in Fortran and now I am trying to include this in a program.

The problem is that I am using Lapack (to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors) and apparently this is creating a conflict with the parallelization routine, because depending on the matrix size it calculates some eigenvalues (wrong values for small sizes, and it doesn't compute them at all for matrices equal or bigger than 10x10).

When I run the program only with one thread it works correctly.

```
program nuevo

use omp_lib  

  implicit none
  integer ::i,j,k,l,kk,jj,red,ok,info,LWORK,stat1 
  integer :: m,n,q,rea,i0,j0,CHUNK,CHUNKSIZE   !!!! rea= number of realizations >1
  PARAMETER(m=10,n=10,rea=12,LWORK=2*m*n,ok=m*n,CHUNKSIZE=rea/2)  
  complex*8 t,aa,tt,ww !! Caution with the dimension of the variables
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(1)::  SEED, OLD
  integer, parameter ::  ikind=selected_real_kind(p=15)
  real (kind=ikind) ::  pi
  real ( kind = 8 ) wtime
  real*8 D, DD(m,n),zz, X(2*m*n*rea), XX(m*n,2*rea), ss, hh, HARVEST(2*n*m*rea), w
  complex*16 A(m*n,m*n), WORK(3*n-2,3*n-2)
  real*8 RWORK(2*m*n), b(m*n), f


!!!!!!!!!!!!RANDOM NUMBERS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


   SEED(1) = 67937
    CALL RANDOM_SEED
    CALL RANDOM_SEED(SIZE=k)
    CALL RANDOM_SEED(GET=OLD(1:k))
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(HARVEST)
        X=HARVEST


!!!!!!!!!!!RANDOM MATRIX!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  

    XX=RESHAPE( X, (/ m*n, 2*rea /) )
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
wtime = omp_get_wtime ( )
!call omp_set_num_threads(1)  

t=1.0d0                  !!  hoppings  

CHUNK=CHUNKSIZE

!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC,CHUNK) ORDERED


 do  jj=0,2*(rea-1),2  !!for the realizations
  w=0.1d0              !! desorder ratio
  ww=n
  q=m*n
  aa=(0.0d0,1.0d0) !! Complex number
   A=0d0
   b=0d0
   f=2/ww

   do j=1,(m*n)
    if (XX(j,jj+1)<0.5) then
       ss=1.0d0
     else
       ss=-1.0d0
     end if
    A(j,j)=ss*0.5d0*w*XX(j,jj+2)        !!  Diagonal terms with slighty random modifications 
    end do

    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    !!!!!!  MATRIX    !!!!!!!!!
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


 !! In the x direction  (i odd)
         do i=1,m,2
            do j=1,n-2,2
               A((j*m)+i,((j+1)*m)+i)=t
            end do
         end do  
!!  In the x direction  (i even)
         do i=2,m,2
            do j=1,n-1,2
               A(((j-1)*m)+i,(j*m)+i)=t
            end do
         end do  

!!  In the y direction  

         do j=1,n
            do i=1,m-1
            A(((j-1)*m)+i,((j-1)*m)+i+1)=t*exp(pi*j*f*aa) !!  phase factor due to the magnetic field 
            end do
         end do
!! Periodic boundaries in x direction


         do i=1,m,2
           A(i,(i+m*n-m))=t
         end do

!!    Periodic boundaries in y direction

            do j=1,n
               A(((j-1)*m)+1,j*m)=t*(exp(-pi*j*f*aa)) 
            end do

!!=========Conjugate===============

         do i0=1,m*n
            do j0=1,m*n
               A(j0,i0)=dconjg(A(i0,j0))
            end do
         end do

call ZHEEV('V', 'U', ok, A, ok, b, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, info) !!Lapack routine
    do i=1,m*n
        write(*,*) b(i)
        write(*,*) ' '
    end do

end do     !! for the realizations


!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

end program nuevo
```

Comment: You might have been better off asking this on StackOverflow, but don't cross-post, the mods may migrate it for you.

Comment: In your `!$OMP PARALLEL` line, you don't specify which variable is shared and which is private. OpenMP takes the default behavior which is that every variable is shared. I advise you do use `!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(NONE)` which is the "implicit none" of OpenMP and will save you a lot of time when you track bugs like this.

Comment: This is a startling hodgepodge of code... It is quite unreadable, with floating point variables of five different types: real of a selected kind for a particular precision, `real(8)`, `real*8` (which need not be the same as either of the previous), `complex*8` and `complex*16`. And that's without going into the variables *names*. You need to clean up your code a bit, try and post a *minimal, complete and verifiable example* for others to be able to help you more effectively.